# Martingale problem on biased random walk

Tags: finance, martingale, random-walk

I am struggling to understand the martingale property of exponential of a biased random walk. For example, in the following problem how do I verify whether the following is a martingale, submartingale or supermartingale? What happens when p=q=1/2?

[image]

Comment: Hi:  You need to calculate $E(S_{n+1} | S_{n})$. If that is $S_n$, then $S_{n}$ is a martingale, If it's greater than$S_{n}$, then it's a super- martingale  and so on and so forth. It's good practice to do the calculation yourself using conditional probability.

Answer (score 1):

A filtration needs to be specified. In this case the natural one is:

$$ {\cal F}_n = \sigma(S_i | 1\leq i\leq n) $$

This makes $S$ adapted. Integrability comes from the boundness of $X$ and $S$.

As per comments, we need then to compute

$$ E[S_{n+1}|{\cal F}_n] $$
and see how it compares with $S_n$.

Note that
$$ E[S_{n+1}|{\cal F}_n] = E[S_{n} {\rm e}^{X_{n+1}}|{\cal F}_n] $$ $$ = S_n E[{\rm e}^{X_{n+1}}|{\cal F}_n] = S_n E[ {\rm e}^{X_{n+1}}], $$

where we have used the fact that $S_n$ is ${\cal F}_n$-measurable and that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of ${\cal F}_n$.

So the key is the computation of expectation
$$E[ {\rm e}^{X_{n+1}}].$$

Comment: Thanks that explains it pretty well. But how do I calculate the last expectation?

Comment: @noisyoscillator This depends on the distribution of $X_{t+1}$ and cannot be answered in general.

Comment: @Cettt So the question itself is ill-posed?

Comment: Sorry, my browser did not show the picture. Simply compute the expaction using basic probability theory